# How to number groups using window function in Postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

I have a table *visits* that shows the navigation of a user in a website. The ultimate goal is to have an estimation of the time a user spent in each area of the website.

```
| user_id | timestamp                 | area_visited  | visit_it       |
| ------- | ------------------------- | ------------- | -------------- |
| 1       | 2021-03-02 19:34:09.708+00| area1         |1               |     
| 1       | 2021-03-02 19:34:16.53+00 | area2         |2               | 
| 1       | 2021-03-02 19:34:18.697+00| area2         |2               | 
| 1       | 2021-03-02 19:34:56.367+00| area1         |3               | 
| 2       | 2021-03-02 19:35:16.53+00 | area1         |1               | 
| 2       | 2021-03-02 19:36:52.53+00 | area3         |2               |    
| 2       | 2021-03-02 19:38:16.53+00 | area3         |3               |
```

I tried to use *dense_rank* but the results is not exactly what I need. I want to increment the *visit_id* field only when the user visits a new area in the website. If the user visits an area, then another one and comes back to the first, I still want that to be considered as a different *visit_id*

I tried the following query but it does not take the chronological order of the visits

```
select *, dense_rank() over (order by user_id,area) as visit_id from visits
```

Then this, but that does not work as each timestamp is unique

```
select *, dense_rank() over (order by user_id,timestamp, area) as visit_id from visits
```

Any idea how to do this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for this :

```
select *
, dense_rank() over (partition by user_id order by timestamp) 
  - dense_rank() over (partition by user_id,area_visited order by timestamp) as visit_id 
from visits
```